# macro expansion with templates

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I'm writing several functions which takes as input the result of a template function:

```
int alg1(Vect3) {...}
...
int algN(Vect3) {...}

void main() {
    alg1( mat.topRightCorner<3,1>() )
}
```

where, if you are curious, `topRightCorner` returns a submatrix of `mat`, a method from the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), where the dimension are placed as template parameters when are known at compile time.

However creating a "shortcut" using a macro to quickly switch between different algorithms (since in the real code the function is called many times), like this

```
#define ALG(X)    ( algN(X) )

ALG( mat.topRightCorner<3,1>() )
```

gives an error, since the macro is correctly expanded but is somehow misinterpreted as with two different parameters, `mat.topRightCorner<3` and `1>()`.

Wrapping the input with brackets will do the trick, but why this behaviour?

Comment: @WhozCraig: `(since in the real code the function is called many times)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `,` is accepted by the preprocessor as a delimiter for a new macro argument, and because the preprocessor doesn't really care that you might have instead meant it as a delimiter for a template parameter list.

To be slightly more precise:

```
ALG( mat.topRightCorner<3,1>() )
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
```

Both of these lexically look like valid macro arguments, and macro parsing takes priority.

On the other hand, the preprocessor is aware of what `()` does, so you can "force" parsing as a single argument that way.